# Sublime binding sequences in JSON keymap files

Tags: sublimetext2

According to this [old documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/key-bindings) of Sublime, it has supported sequence key bindings like "ctrl+t,u" for XML based keymap files.

Is this still supported in JSON keymap files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+e","ctrl+f"], "command": "reindent"} 
]
```